# How to prevent iOS Messages app from cropping pasted image?

Tags: ios, keyboard, sms, copy-paste, imessage

I'm working on an app that lets people copy and paste images. The image is copied like this:

```
NSString *path =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"circle" ofType:@"png"];
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
[pasteboard setData:data forPasteboardType:@"public.png"];
```

When then pasting in the Notes app, it works fine. However in the Messages app, it crops the right side of the image. Is there a way to prevent this?

[image][image]

Comment: Did you able to solve your problem. I'm also facing this problem. So, want you to post your answer if you would have resolved and get the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot prevent this, since that was Apple's UI idea. Although you can put a transparent borders into your image so even though Messages.app clips the image the main part of it still be visible.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.